# How to create a SQL query in PHP with differents variables

Tags: php, android, mysql, get

I have a problem when I create a sql query which depends on many variables that the user select in different checkboxes.
I make a httprequest GET and them, when I proposed to create the query, I check the variable and I create the query, gradually. I show you the PHP code:

```
$link =  mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die('No se pudo conectar: '  . mysql_error());
//echo 'Conectado satisfactoriamente';
mysql_select_db('Agenda Juvenil') or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos');
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

$query="SELECT id, title, barrio_smultiple, coordenadas_p_0_coordinate,     coordenadas_p_1_coordinate, gratuita_b FROM eventosDiarios WHERE";

// check for post data

if (isset($_GET['franjas0'])){
 $franja0 = $_GET['franjas0'];
 $query.="franja_smultiple IN ('$franja0'";
 }

if (isset($_GET['franjas1'])){
 $franja1 = $_GET['franjas1'];
 $query.=",'$franja1'";
 }

if (isset($_GET['franjas2'])){
 $franja2 = $_GET['franjas2'];
 $query.=",'$franja2'";
 }

$query.=")";

// get a product from products table
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Consulta fallida: ' . mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["eventos"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $evento = array();
    $evento["id"] = $row["id"];
    $evento["title"] = $row["title"];
    $evento["barrio_smultiple"] = $row["barrio_smultiple"];

    $evento["coordenadas_p_0_coordinate"] = $row["coordenadas_p_0_coordinate"];
    $evento["coordenadas_p_1_coordinate"] = $row["coordenadas_p_1_coordinate"];
    $evento["gratuita_b"] = $row["gratuita_b"];


    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["eventos"], $evento);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);

} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No se han encontrado eventos";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

The query must return something, but I have nothing. The variables are sent throught

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

I am using Android.
Can someone help me please??

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: WHERE ???? ur quesry is incomplete

Comment: @mona because OP is appending to the variable, perhaps?

Comment: @vld yup, but what if First if condition fails

Comment: @mona we actually don't know if it can fail or not because of that. I'd suggest OP to provide more code so we can say something more concrete. As it stands, OP says the query does not return anything, so I sort of assume the generated query is valid but the actual conditional logic is not, thus nothing gets returned.

Comment: @Vld I am sure first if doesn't fail because I always click on this option. The problem is that the query returns nothing. Is a good way to create the query like this?

Comment: Generally, what _I_ would do (which is may not be correct, not sure) is to collect all the arguments you get in an array (obviously, only the ones you do get - if a user doesn't select option C don't include it), and then if you have stuff in the array, append the WHERE clause to the SQL and implode the array into arguments for it. Also, I should note, you would need to filter the values before shoving them in the array because your code right now is vulnerable to SQL injection. However, I don't know why your SELECT is not returning anything - I suppose the SQL is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks everybody, the mistake was the first query should finish with a space, because then when i make the concat the two words are together and the query is wrong. @Vld thanks for your advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs to have a space after the WHERE. It needs to say

```
...b FROM eventosDiarios WHERE ";
```

rather than

```
....b FROM eventosDiarios WHERE";
```

or you'll get an illformed query.